# How can I use LoadBalancer type service on GCE with kubeadm?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I made a kubernetes cluster using kubeadm on GCE(not GKE), and I am using Calico as CNI.

I want to make ingress-nginx LoadBalancer, so expect to use 80/443 ports for external connection instead of NodePort port range. But when I use `LoadBalancer` for service type, the `EXTERNAL-IP` is showing as `<pending>`.

```
$ kubectl get svc -n ingress-nginx
NAME                                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.105.43.38     <pending>     80:30269/TCP,443:31275/TCP   7d20h
ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.103.170.208   <none>        443/TCP                      7d20h
```

I searched many times about this issue, but many of articles were for GKE.

How can I use `LoadBalancer` on GCE?

Answer (score 0):

If nothing obvious is showing up in the events, then being stuck on pending sounds like a quota issue. You can check your [forwarding rules](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/forwarding-rule-concepts), [target proxies](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/target-proxies), or [target pools](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/target-pools) (to name a few) to see if you are running into a limiter. If so you can just [increase the quota in the GCP console](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota)

Comment: Thank you for answer! I have a question about gcloud load balancer. I have no load balancer yet for my VM instances. What type of load balancer is needed to use as kubernetes service LoadBalancer type? In [docs](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/choosing-load-balancer), it seems there are internal/external and TCP-UDP/HTTP(S). I cannot find any explanation abount this in docs.

Comment: in the link you just sent they [provide comparisons](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/choosing-load-balancer#load_balancing_aspects) for the types. I would read through that to see which one fits your needs.